# How do I get my Flash CS4 buttons to direct the user to another URL?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

My apologies if this has been fully addressed before, but I've read through several other threads and still can't seem to get my file to work.

My actionscript code is at the bottom of this message.  I created it using instructions from the Adobe website:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fd7.html

I believe I've all of my objects set to the correct type of symbol (button) and all of my instances are named appropriately (see screenshot here:  www.footprintsfamilyphoto.com/wp-content/themes/Footprints/images/flash_buttonissue.jpg)

Action Script here.  Let me know if you have suggestions!  (Note:  I am very new to Flash):

```
stop ();


function babieschildren(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("babies children method was called!!!");
    var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.footprintsfamilyphoto.com/portfolio/babies-children"); 
    navigateToURL(targetURL, "_self"); 
}

bc_btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, babieschildren);
bc_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, babieschildren);


function families(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("families method was called!!!");
    var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.footprintsfamilyphoto.com/portfolio/families"); 
    navigateToURL(targetURL, "_self"); 
}

f_btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, families);
f_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, families);


function couplesweddings(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("couples weddings method was called!!!");
    var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.footprintsfamilyphoto.com/portfolio/couples-weddings"); 
    navigateToURL(targetURL, "_self"); 
}

cw_btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, couplesweddings);
cw_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, couplesweddings);
```

Additional description of Flash file - file is an approx 5 second animation that should stop on the last frame.  The last frame contains 6 buttons which should route the user to 3 different pages of the website. Refer to screenshot image link above.

---

Alright, I tried a couple more things, I changed the "families" function to "fams" since for some reason it was telling me that it was a duplicate function.  That resolved the looping issue (the file was looping instead of stopping on the frame where these buttons are located, and I was receiving compilation errors about the families function - "duplicate function definition" and "incompatible override" - I'm fairly confident it's not a duplicate function, as this is the only action script that I have in this entire file...).

Now it stops on the right frame, the compilation errors appear to be resolved, but I don't see the trace statements in the output box when I click on the buttons.  I do get an initial error in the output box when I test the movie, it reads:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at Portfolio_fla::MainTimeline/frame133()

Can anyone let me know what that means?

i've checked and rechecked all the button names (and instance names), they're all there, right in the same frame as the action script (frame 133), so that shouldn't be causing the 1009.

Also just removed each function and addEventListener set one by one and tested the movie, but the 1009 error persisted in all 3 cases. I do not get the 1009 error if I delete all of the code other than "stop ();" and test the movie.

---

Note: I've opened a new, more specific question regarding the 1009 error here:
stackoverflow.com/questions/2948119/flash-buttons-dont-work-typeerror-error-1009-cannot-access-a-property-or-met

Comment: someone please edit this post to correctly format the source code :)

Comment: sorry about that - I think it's in shape now!

Comment: Is `families` the name of a class - are you using the term anywhere else at all? Do you have the line number at which the 1009 error occurs?

Comment: that's the whole error (the 1009), didn't give a line number.

there is a layer called "families", not sure if that makes a difference.  but that's it.

Comment: I don't have much experience with CS4 ide - I'll delete my answer (you can still view it), so that this question will remain as unanswered and you might get more views.

Comment: Have you tried tracing some of the properties the buttons to see if the instances (f_btn.x ?  ..etc) are linked to what is actually on stage ? [I know you said you rechecked the names .. it is worth the try]

Comment: Thanks phwd - I added the "trace" statement for each function (as indicated in the code above), if that's what you mean?  And the result was that the trace statements did NOT appear in the output box when I'd click on the buttons in the test movie.  But I'm not clear as to why, other than the 1009 error detailed above and in my new question (which I don't know how to resolve).  Let me know if you have any ideas - or if I misinterpreted what you meant by "tracing some of the properties" of the buttons (again - very new at this!).

Answer (score 1):

You code looks fine. Add trace statements in the methods to make sure they're indeed called. Also check for any pop-up blockers; when you call [navigateToURL](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()) without the second parameter, Flash will try to create a new window to open the URL in. Unfortunately for us developers, (and fortunately for users), most of the pop-up blockers will prevent this from happening. Add the second parameter to your calls and see if it works.

```
navigateToURL(targetURL, "_self");
```

Note that this will cause the new URL to be loaded in the current window/tab, effectively replacing the page that has your SWF

Comment: Thanks for your response - I updated the targetURL with the "_self" parameter.

However, my buttons still aren't fundamentally working.  With the code above, my test movie fails to stop on the last frame and just continues to loop.  I also get error messages saying that the "families" function is a duplicate function (it's not, is it?  i haven't used any other a.s. in this file).  

If I remove everything except the "stop ();" line, my test movie DOES stop on the last frame, and my cursor indicates that the appropriate objects are buttons. but, of course, they don't do anything.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Also - I don't know what you mean by "Add trace statements in the methods to make sure they're indeed called."  Could you explain in more detail?  (Again, I'm really new to this.)

Comment: @golden I think the problem is the position of code - you'll have to move the code to first frame or something.

Comment: @golden add `trace("babies children method was called!!!");` as the first line of the `babieschildren` method and so on. Now check the output panel of the CS4 to see if anything is printed when you click on the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and suggestions.  I moved all of the code underneath the "stop ();" line to the first frame in the actions layer (is that what you meant?), but still the same result - the test movie loops rather than stopping on the last frame, and I'm getting the same error messages regarding my "button" code ("incompatible override" and "duplicate function definition", referring to the "families" function).

Comment: Attempted a few more things - added info to the initial question post, let me know if that sheds any light on what the issue might be.